# How to make units bold in math environment using siunitx package?

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx

I am trying to write a unit for decibel (dB) inside a math environment using siunitx package and I cannot figure out how to make it bold.

I understand that instead of using siunitx package and math mode I can just write dB, but I want to figure out how to do it this way.

I have tried \boldmath and \boldsymbol{} but none of them are working.

---

Here is my code.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SS}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Permissible Noise Exposures}}\\
    \toprule
    %\rowcolor{clc!50}
    \textbf{Duration per Day (in hours)} & \textbf{Sound Level (in \boldmath $\si{dB}$ \footnotemark)} \\
    \midrule
    8 & 90 \\
    6 & 92 \\
    4 & 95 \\
    3 & 97 \\
    2 & 100 \\
    1 & 105 \\
    0.5 & 110 \\
    $\mathtt{\leq}$0.25 & 115 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Permissible Noise Exposures}
\subcaption*{Source: 29 CFR 1910.95, Table G-16}
\label{tab:noise-exposure} 
\end{table}\bigskip
\footnotetext{When measured on the A scale of a standard sound level meter at slow response.}
```

---

And this is the output. Notice that the dB symbol is not bolded. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add the option `detect-weight` to the `\si`, `\SI`, and `\num` instructions. The option informs `siunitx` that it should utilize information about the font weight of the surrounding material; if that font weight happens to be **bold**, it'll be applied to the arguments of `\si`, `\SI`, and `\num`.

For more information about utilizing font-related information from the commands' surrounding material, see section 5.2, "Detecting fonts", of the package's [user guide](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\begin{document}
\textbf{Sound Level (in \si{dB})}

\textbf{Sound Level (in \si[detect-weight]{dB})}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This completely answeres my question!